# .htaccess - Redirect specific page with php parameters

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have the following url
`http://mywebsite.com/browse-test.php?v=myname`

I want it to be redirected to this instead
`http://mywebsite.com/myname`

This is what I tried so far

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mywebsite.com/browse-test.php?v=$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mywebsite.com/$1 [L,R=302]
```

When I looked for an answer on this website and google I didn't find any examples that made a redirect based on on a specific file and php url paramater.

Comment: Your RewriteCond can never be true. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Hi, How do I go about it please as I'm not familiar with apache?

Comment: Do you want just this file browse-test.php to redirect to mywebsite.com/myname?

Comment: I'd like all mywebsite.com/browse-test.php?v=myname to redirect to mywebsite.com/myname please

Answer (score 1):

This code should help.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /+browser-test\.php\?v=([^&\s]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /browse-test.php?v=$1 [L]
```

Having a look at the mod_rewrite docs to get a better understanding as MrTux noted is highly suggested to better understand the different options.